# Inherited controls not refreshing correctly

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have 2 buttons that have similar functions so I created a base button class and derived button classes.

The problem I'm having is that if I put a child button on a form, make some changes on the base button and rebuild it, the child button on the form does not reflect the changes. The new child button put on the form after the rebuild, it has the changed properties. Basically, the control that was already put on the form does not refresh after the base control is rebuilt.

I can't refresh the controls on designer since there are too many of them. I'm guessing that if a control is put on a form, it's properties are set(?). Maybe I'm not good enough with inheritance and missing something here.

I would like to know how to refresh the child controls that were put on the form before base control was modified.

**UPDATE** with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

Here is the example in VB.NET.

```
Public Class ButtonA
    Public Sub New()
        Me.Size = New Size(200, 200)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ButtonB
    Inherits ButtonA
End Class
```

After instance of ButtonB called btnB is put on a form, ButtonA's default size changes to

```
Me.Size = New Size(300, 300)
```

After the project is rebuilt, when I look back on the designer view, btnB's size is still (200, 200), not (300, 300) as it's base default size.

Size is just used as an example, it applies to any properties.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use just the [tag:winforms] tag and not C# or VB.NET? Putting both tags on your question is generally wrong, as neither a question nor an answer can be about both C# and VB.NET at the same time. As for the question itself: _" if a control is put on a form, it's properties are set"_ -- yes and no. Properties are set in the *.Designer.cs file if they have values other than the control's default value. Without a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're doing and what the precise problem is, there's no way to answer the question.

Comment: I'm sorry that I do not understand what you guys mean. This is a general question, not language specific since it both happened to my winform project in C# and VB.NET. They are using the same .NET framework and I'm confused why putting both tags is considered wrong. If C# can do something, VB.NET can do the same most of the time even though there will be some difference in syntax. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: _"I'm confused why putting both tags is considered wrong"_ -- because (as you put it) _"This is a general question, not language specific"_. The tags you use on your question indicate what part(s) of the problem you are actually needing help with. Language tags indicate the language being used. If you don't care what language, there's no need to provide language tags. You *should* include the "winforms" tag, since your question is apparently involving Winforms features.

Comment: I DO care the language, .NET, therefore I put C# and VB.NET. I'm not asking this question in Java or Python. Winform is part of .NET framework.   By your logic, you are saying most of the questions in stackoverflow have invalid tags.

Comment: @fwan - By *your* logic, you should have tagged your question with F# as well, since that language is part of the .NET framework.

Comment: Drop the notion of a default size.  The constructor code provides an *initial size*

Comment: @Tim I'm just going stop this tag arguments. I will add winform tag and this should do it. I was just not satisfied with Peter's comment that I must pick a language for it even though both C# and VB.NET could be used for winform project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing values of properties that he designer, by design, must not use, once you have placed a control on the form.  The designer allows you to put a control of a certain class in you form and, **when first inserted** will take a clue as to what the size should be from that control. It will then assign that size to that control within this form. You are at liberty, at any time, to modify the form by changing the size or location of any form within that form. The designer will keep track of all of this.

If you now modify the source code to have a different 'default' value for the size, then, that will **not** be reflected on the form that was created prior to the size being changed - that's because the control already exists on your form and the designer therefore no longer has to make make any changes to the size.

If you do want to override this behaviour you will have to remove the assignment of the Size property in the designer code (Form.Desisgner.cs - in C# or its VB equivalent). But beware - next time you fire up the designer it will probably put the size back in there.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. It was very clear to me. I should be careful about using inheriting controls since two same controls might have different default values.